# Set utf8proc or Unicode 9 in Gnome Terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, unicode, utf-8

Emojis are messing up my Neovim font widths. The github forum here: https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5149 shows a few approaches, one of which is to get a terminal application that has utf8proc or Unicode 9.

Is there a way to upgrade or set Gnome Terminal to use Unicode 9 or utf8proc?

Comment: Could you please give a detailed description of the _actual_ problem you are trying to solve in the first place? Also details about your system, e.g. Ubuntu version?

Comment: Unicode 9 was released mid-2016, 6.5 years ago. If you're using Ubuntu 18.04-ish or newer, I'm fairly certain that your GNOME Terminal uses Unicode database version 9 or later. The problem, and thus the fix to that problem, is not hereabouts.